# Pesquisa por similaridade PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer uma pesquisa por similaridade em um campo do tipo  `character varying` no PostgreSql.

Por exemplo: O nome que tenho gravado na tabela no campo nome é `Tauros` e estou procurando `Taurros`. Queria algo que me retornasse o grau de similaridade entre o que foi digitado e o que eu encontrei.

Lembrando que estou utilizando a versão 8.4 do postgresql e também não tenho como fazer instalações no servidor, pois é de uma empresa que divido o banco. Ou seja, não posso utilizar o módulo fuzzystrmatch, com as funções `soundex()` e `difference()`

Comment: Conforme comentei, não seria possível utilizar as novas funções, pois essas funções depende de bibliotecas que tem que ser instalada e eu não tenho acesso. Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não creio que algum banco de dados tenha nativamente alguma função que retorne resultados por similaridade. Mas pelas pesquisas que fiz há vários algoritmos que podem solucionar seu problema.

Leia os posts [deste fórum](http://www.guj.com.br/java/293343-similaridade-de-nomes-resolvido), mais abaixo você verá que um usuário postou um script com algumas funções para PostgreSQL que provavelmente vão te ajudar.